# How to unit test my gradle script?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guide for Testing Gradle Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045292/guide-for-testing-gradle-scripts)

I'm going to write gradle scripts in order to automate builds and deployments.
As i like TDD I would like to perform unit tests to my gradle script, can anyone tell me please how can I achieve such a thing?

thanks

Comment: yes looks like its a duplicate of it, but i didn't find there a nice solution...

Comment: You could start a bounty on the other question.